# Visualizing Stockchart with Coreplot Stockprice appears very flat

Tags: ios, swift, core-plot, stock

I tried,

- I set the y-axis very narrow to make small price movements appear normal, it didn't help
- API results checked they are fine
- Other Diagramtypes (Points/ Line...) didnt fix the problem

I'm only using the yAxis no need for xAxis

here my whole code

My ChartViewController

```
    //
//  ChartViewController.swift
//  MCOS
//
//  Created by Burhan Cankurt on 01.09.23.
//

import UIKit
import CorePlot

class ChartViewController: UIViewController, CPTScatterPlotDataSource, CPTScatterPlotDelegate, CPTAxisDelegate {

    var ArrayStockClose: [(date: String, close: Double)] = []
    @IBOutlet weak var graphHostingView: CPTGraphHostingView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        chartViewStockClose(with: .fiveMinute)
    }
    
    func chartViewStockClose(with timeFrame: TimeFrame) {
        print("chartViewStockClose called") // Debug
        let fetcher = chartFetcherStockClose()
        chartLoadStockClose(with: timeFrame, fetcher: fetcher) { [weak self] result in
            print("chartLoadStockClose completion called") // Debug
            switch result {
            case .success(let data):
                self?.ArrayStockClose = data
                print("Daten im ViewController: \(data) und  zählung \(data.count)")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print("initializeGraph called") // Debug
                    // Hier können Sie Ihren Graphen initialisieren oder aktualisieren
                    self?.initializeGraph()
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error fetching data: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func initializeGraph() {
        // Konfigurieren Sie die Ansicht und den Graphen
        configureGraphView(for: graphHostingView, plotData: ArrayStockClose, delegate: self) // Angenommen, Sie haben eine Funktion namens configureGraphView
        // Konfigurieren Sie den Plot
        configurePlot(for: graphHostingView, dataSource: self, delegate: self) // Angenommen, Sie haben eine Funktion namens configurePlot
    }
}

// Erweiterung für CorePlot Datenquelle und Delegat
extension ChartViewController {
    
    func numberOfRecords(for plot: CPTPlot) -> UInt {
        print("numberOfRecords called, count: \(ArrayStockClose.count)")
        return UInt(ArrayStockClose.count)
    }

    func number(for plot: CPTPlot, field: UInt, record: UInt) -> Any? {
        print("number called for field: \(field), record: \(record)")
        switch CPTScatterPlotField(rawValue: Int(field)) {
        case .X:
            return NSNumber(value: record)  // Da wir die X-Achse nicht verwenden, können wir einfach den Index verwenden
        case .Y:
            return NSNumber(value: ArrayStockClose[Int(record)].close)
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

My ChartFetcherStockClose

```
//
//  ChartFetcherStockClose.swift
//  MCOS
//
//  Created by Burhan Cankurt on 01.09.23.
//

import Foundation

import Foundation

class chartFetcherStockClose {
    func fetch(url: URL, completion: @escaping (Result<[(date: String, close: Double)], Error>) -> Void) {
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                completion(.failure(error))
                return
            }
            guard let data = data else {
                completion(.failure(NSError(domain: "No data", code: 0, userInfo: nil)))
                return
            }
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let stockData = try decoder.decode([StructStockClose].self, from: data)
                // Sortiere die Datenpunkte nach dem Datum
                let sortedStockData = stockData.sorted { $0.date < $1.date }
                // Erstelle ein leeres Array, um die Ergebnisse zu speichern.
                var resultArray: [(date: String, close: Double)] = []
                // Durchlaufe jedes Element in sortedStockData.
                for data in sortedStockData {
                    resultArray.append((date: data.date, close: data.close))
                }
                // Rufe den Completion Handler mit dem Ergebnis-Array auf.
                completion(.success(resultArray))
            } catch {
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}// Class End
```

My ChartLoadStockClose

```
//
//  ChartLoadStockClose.swift
//  MCOS
//
//  Created by Burhan Cankurt on 01.09.23.
//

import Foundation

enum TimeFrame {
    case oneMinute
    case fiveMinute
    case fifteenMinute
    case thirtyMinute
    case oneHour
    case fourHour
    case oneDay
}

func chartLoadStockClose(with timeFrame: TimeFrame, fetcher: chartFetcherStockClose, completion: @escaping (Result<[(date: String, close: Double)], Error>) -> Void) {
    let timeFrameParameter: String
    switch timeFrame {
    case .oneMinute: timeFrameParameter = "1min"
    case .fiveMinute: timeFrameParameter = "5min"
    case .fifteenMinute: timeFrameParameter = "15min"
    case .thirtyMinute: timeFrameParameter = "30min"
    case .oneHour: timeFrameParameter = "1hour"
    case .fourHour: timeFrameParameter = "4hour"
    case .oneDay: timeFrameParameter = "1day"
    }
    
    let url = URL(string: "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/historical-chart/\(timeFrameParameter)/AAPL?apikey=BLABLABLA")!
    
    fetcher.fetch(url: url) { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let data):
            // Verwende nur die letzten 48 Datenpunkte
            let filteredData = Array(data.suffix(48))
            completion(.success(filteredData))
        case .failure(let error):
            completion(.failure(error))
        }
    }
}
```

My ChartConfigureGraphView

```
//
//  ChartConfigureGraphView.swift
//  MCOS
//
//  Created by Burhan Cankurt on 01.09.23.
//

import CorePlot
import UIKit

func configureGraphView(for graphView: CPTGraphHostingView, plotData: [(date: String, close: Double)], delegate: CPTAxisDelegate) {
    print("configureGraphView called") // Debug
    graphView.allowPinchScaling = false
    // Configure graph
    let graph = CPTXYGraph(frame: graphView.bounds)
    graph.plotAreaFrame?.masksToBorder = false
    graphView.hostedGraph = graph
    graph.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    graph.paddingBottom = 40.0
    graph.paddingLeft = 50.0
    graph.paddingTop = 30.0
    graph.paddingRight = 5.0
    
    // Set plot space
    let yMin = plotData.min(by: { $0.close < $1.close })?.close ?? 0
    let yMax = plotData.max(by: { $0.close < $1.close })?.close ?? 0

    print("yMin: \(yMin)") // Debug
    print("yMax: \(yMax)") // Debug

    let yRange = yMax - yMin
    let paddingPercentage = 0.05

    print("yRange: \(yRange)") // Debug

    let yMinAdjusted = yMin - (yRange * paddingPercentage)
    let yMaxAdjusted = yMax + (yRange * paddingPercentage)

    print("yMinAdjusted: \(yMinAdjusted)") // Debug
    print("yMaxAdjusted: \(yMaxAdjusted)") // Debug
    
    guard let plotSpace = graph.defaultPlotSpace as? CPTXYPlotSpace else { return }

    plotSpace.yRange = CPTPlotRange(locationDecimal: CPTDecimalFromDouble(yMinAdjusted), lengthDecimal: CPTDecimalFromDouble(yMaxAdjusted - yMinAdjusted))
    
    // Configure axes
    let axisSet = graph.axisSet as! CPTXYAxisSet
    
    let axisTextStyle = CPTMutableTextStyle()
    axisTextStyle.color = CPTColor.white()
    axisTextStyle.fontName = "HelveticaNeue-Bold"
    axisTextStyle.fontSize = 10.0
    axisTextStyle.textAlignment = .center

    if let x = axisSet.xAxis {
        x.isHidden = true  // Versteckt die X-Achse
    }

    if let y = axisSet.yAxis {
        print("Configuring yAxis") // Debug
        y.majorIntervalLength = NSNumber(value: Double((yMaxAdjusted - yMinAdjusted) / 10.0))  // Dynamically adjust the interval
        y.minorTicksPerInterval = 5
        y.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle
        y.axisConstraints = CPTConstraints(lowerOffset: 0.0)
        y.delegate = delegate
    }
}
```

My Struct

```
//
//  Structs.swift
//  MCOS
//
//  Created by Burhan Cankurt on 01.09.23.
//

import Foundation

struct StructStockClose: Decodable {
    let close: Double
    let date: String
}
```

My ChartConfigurePlot

```
//
//  ChartConfigurePlot.swift
//  MCOS
//
//  Created by Burhan Cankurt on 01.09.23.
//

import CorePlot
import UIKit

func configurePlot(for graphView: CPTGraphHostingView, dataSource: CPTScatterPlotDataSource, delegate: CPTScatterPlotDelegate) {
    print("configurePlot called") // Debug
    let plot = CPTScatterPlot()
    let plotLineStile = CPTMutableLineStyle()
    plotLineStile.lineJoin = .round
    plotLineStile.lineCap = .round
    plotLineStile.lineWidth = 2
    plotLineStile.lineColor = CPTColor.white()
    plot.dataLineStyle = plotLineStile
    plot.curvedInterpolationOption = .catmullCustomAlpha
    plot.interpolation = .curved
    plot.identifier = "coreplot-graph" as NSCoding & NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol
    guard let graph = graphView.hostedGraph else { return }
    plot.dataSource = dataSource
    plot.delegate = delegate
    graph.add(plot, to: graph.defaultPlotSpace)
}
```

Comment: We need some more information on what you are getting vs what you are expecting. We can't check your data, as we can't get anything from the URL in your code... but, if I replace your `chartViewStockClose()` func with this: https://pastebin.com/T1EAipNs ... I get this output from the two sets of "sample close data":  https://i.stack.imgur.com/57RmU.png

Comment: pls see my answer under this comment, thx for ur help but now im facing a more strange problem

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with the visulation the problem was no matter if u use the xAxis or not u need the timestamps after creating this code

MyDateHelpers

```
//
//  DateHelpers.swift
//  MCOS
//
//  Created by Burhan Cankurt on 02.09.23.
//

import Foundation


func convertDateToTimestamp(_ date: String) -> Double {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" // Anpassung an Ihr Datumsformat
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    
    guard let dateObject = dateFormatter.date(from: date) else {
        print("Fehler beim Konvertieren des Datums: \(date)")
        return 0.0
    }
    
    let timestamp = dateObject.timeIntervalSince1970
    print("Zeitstempel für Datum \(date): \(timestamp)")
    return timestamp
}
```

and using it in my ChartViewController here

```
// Erweiterung für CorePlot Datenquelle und Delegat
extension ChartViewController {
    
    func numberOfRecords(for plot: CPTPlot) -> UInt {
        print("Anzahl der Datenpunkte: \(ArrayStockClose.count)")
        return UInt(ArrayStockClose.count)
    }

    func number(for plot: CPTPlot, field: UInt, record: UInt) -> Any? {
        switch CPTScatterPlotField(rawValue: Int(field)) {
        case .X:
            return NSNumber(value: convertDateToTimestamp(ArrayStockClose[Int(record)].date))  // Verwenden Sie den Zeitstempel
        case .Y:
            return NSNumber(value: ArrayStockClose[Int(record)].close)
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

the Visulation worked correct but now im facing a very strange problem, Timeframe 1Minute and 5 Minutes works correct but if use a Timeframe above 5Minute i receive this error

```
Zeitstempel für Datum 2023-09-01 15:00:00: 1693580400.0
Zeitstempel für Datum 2023-09-01 15:15:00: 1693581300.0
Zeitstempel für Datum 2023-09-01 15:30:00: 1693582200.0
Zeitstempel für Datum 2023-09-01 15:45:00: 1693583100.0
Zeitstempel für Datum 2023-09-01 16:00:00: 1693584000.0
Anzahl der Datenpunkte: 48
Anzahl der Datenpunkte: 48
2023-09-03 23:13:45.924826+0200 MCOS[40996:1540827] [Render] CoreAnimation: Message::send_message() returned 0x1000000e
2023-09-03 23:13:45.925018+0200 MCOS[40996:1540827] [API] Failed to commit transaction (client=0x1d461d53) [0x1000000e (ipc/send) msg too large]
```

What did i tried?

- Api works correct and delivers enough datapoints also for higher
- Laptop has enough ressources to face the performance

Strange: if u reduce my datapoints from 48 to 20 as example i get the chart loaded on higher timeframe 15Minutes and when i reduce it to 10 it loads also higher timeframe chart 30 Minutes

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: I created a free account and got an api key to use your URL to retrieve data... I do **NOT** get the error you posted -- but, I do **NOT** get any output on the graph view (other than the y-axis values).

Comment: thx for ur efforts Sir unfortunately i was not able to solve the problem however icreated the whole project from the scratch now it works i dont know why but finally it works.

Comment: OK - glad you have your task working now. But, as this will not help anyone else, you should probably delete your question.